# the markup document following the root element must be well formed

Tags: java, jsf

I am getting the following error while saving my `faces-config.xml`:

```
the markup document following the root element must be well formed
```

And my xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC 
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>UserBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.jsfcompref.register.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/register.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/confirm.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

I have closed all the tags properly, still I am getting this error.

Comment: is it a full document? if it is, then it has 2 root elements and that is not allowed in XML

Comment: give the whole document.

Answer (score 9):

The open tag `<faces-config>` is missing. Put it between `<DOCTYPE...>` and `<managed-bean>`.

Comment: what more obvious than that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use any JSF IDE, so that you are not bothered with such markup issues. Virtually all IDE's supporting JSF provide a GUI for handling faces-config.xml file